# Remove grey line around table slider jquery item

Tags: jquery, html, css

Initially, I it was a plain jquery slider item with no grey line around the item image.Then I decided to insert the price below the item image and link. I put the item html coding inside a table and now a grey line appears around the item as shown on www.dailycrazydeals.com.

The html code is as shown below:

```
<h1>Daily Deals</h1>
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
<ul>
    <li>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="center">

<a href="#"><img src="" alt="img11"><h4>test</h4></a>
<hr width="130%" noshade>
   </li>
</td>
</tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td>WAS:</td>
                    <td class="strikethrough">$179.95</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>YOU SAVE:<hr width="130%" noshade></td>
                    <td>$40.00<hr width="100%" noshade></td>
                </tr>
<tr>
<td>$139.95</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: post your http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: and the CSS..? It's probably best if you pop the relevant code in to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/LdCnK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override this border in your style.css :

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this in your css :

```
table {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
text-align: left;
padding: 5px;
}
```

the gray border caused by `border: 1px solid #ddd;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, when u added the items you misplaced hr tag

```
<hr width="130%" noshade>
```

just remove it, and u get:

```
<h1>Daily Deals</h1>
<div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
<ul>
    <li>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="center">

<a href="#"><img src="" alt="img11"><h4>test</h4></a>
<hr width="130%" noshade>
   </li>
</td>
</tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td>WAS:</td>
                    <td class="strikethrough">$179.95</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>YOU SAVE:</td>
                    <td>$40.00</td>
                </tr>
<tr>
<td>$139.95</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```